# Animation during loading of a div

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I want to use a spining animation during the loading of a page but only for a div content (during the generation of à big table in that div) .

I try to use fancybox.showLoading() and hideLoading(), because I already use fancybox2 for other things, but without result ....

Do you have somme ideas to help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-awesome-image-preloader/

it works fine and is reusable.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but it seems to be difficult to adapt the code for html content and not a picture...